# How heavy are akka actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am aware this is a very imprecise question and might be deemed inappropriate for stackoverflow. Unfortunately smaller applications (in terms of the number of actors) and 'tutorial-like' ones don't help me develop intuition about the overhead of message dispatch and a swift spot for granularity between a 'scala object' and a 'CORBA object'.

While almost certainly keeping a state of conversation with a client for example deserves an actor, in most real use cases it would involve conditional/parallel/alternative interactions modeled by many classes. This leaves the choice between treating actors as facades to quite complex services, similar to the justly retired EJB, or akin to smalltalk objects, firing messages between each other willy-nilly whenever communication can possibly be implemented in an asynchronous manner.

Apart from the overhead of message passing itself, there will also be overhead involved with lifecycle management, and I am wary of potential problems caused by chained-restarts of whole subtrees of actors due to exceptions or other errors in their root.

For the sake of this question we may assume that vast majority of the communication happens within a single machine and network crossing is insignificant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by an "overhead of message passing itself". 
When network/serialisation is not involved then the overhead is negligible: one side pushes a message in a queue, another reads it from it.

Akka claims that it can go as fast as 50 millions messages per second on a single machine. This means that you wouldn't use actors just as façade for complex subsystems. You would rather model them as mush smaller "working units". They can be more complex compare to smalltalk objects when convenient. You could have, say, `KafkaConsumerActor` which would utilise internally other "normal" classes such as Connection, Configuration, etc., these don't have to be akka actors. But it is still small enough to be a simple working unit doing one simple thing (consuming a message and sending it somewhere).
50 millions a second is really a lot.

A memory footprint is also extremely small. Akka itself claims that you can have ~2.5 millions actors for just 1GB of heap. Compare to what a typical system does it is, indeed, nothing.

As for lifecycle, creating an actor is not much heavier than creating an class instance and a mailbox so I don't really expect it to be that significant.
Saying that, typically you don't have many actors in your system that would handle one message and die. Normally you spawn actors which live much longer. Like, an actor that calculates your mortgage repayments based on parameters you provide doesn't have any reason to die at all.
Also Akka makes it very simple to use actor pools (different kinds of them).
So performance here is very tweakable.

Last point is that you should compare Akka overhead in a context. For example, if your system is doing database queries, or serving/performing HTTP requests, or even doing significant IO of some sort, then probably overhead of these activities makes overhead of Akka so insignificant so you wouldn't even bother thinking about it. Like a roundtrip to the DB for 50 millis would be an equivalent of an overhead from ~2.5 millions akka messages. Does it matter?

So can you find an edge case scenario where Akka would force you to pay performance penalties? Probably. Akka is not a golden hammer (and nothing is).
But with all the above in mind you should think if it is Akka that is a performance bottleneck in your specific context or you are wasting time in micro-optimisation.

Comment: Thanks for some hard numbers. I was thinking about it in the context of handling individual UDP/IP packets, where a single actor would need to take note of each one of them and only after recognizing the conversation it is a part of delegating to the responsible actor, quite often being created on the spot. While it is possible to remove that single point of contention, it would significantly increase the complexity and never be completely transpart to the clients, which are numerous but small low-level devices that can run only very simple software.